# Сопоставление в Entity Framework сущьностей и таблиц

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Подскажите пожалуйста такой вопрос - как лучше сопоставить в EF следующее:
Предположим есть класс с тремя свойствами - ID, Num1, Num2
И две таблицы в базе - каждая содержит ID, Num1, Num2
Как лучше сделать создать для класса два потомка и привязать каждого потомка к своей таблице?

Comment: Уточните: у вас EF или EF Core? Укажите точную версию.

Comment: Смотрите [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration). Вам нужна TPT - table-per-type configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас верно понял, то вы хотите маппить одну сущность на две таблицы в БД.
Если это так, то можно воспользоваться `DbModelBuilder` и создать маппинг на две таблицы. Например

```
public partial class Employee  
{   
   public int EmployeeId { get; set; }   
   public string Code { get; set; }  
   public string Name { get; set; }  
} 

    public partial class Model : DbContext  
    {  
       public Model() : base("name=EntityModel")  
       {  
          Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;  
       }  
       public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }  
    
       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
       {  
          modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()  
          .Map(map => map.ToTable("EmployeeTest1"))  
          .Map(map => map.ToTable("EmployeeTest2"));  
       }  
    }
```

Ответ взят отсюда:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38389600/mapping-entity-framework-model-to-multiple-tables
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611079/entity-framework-map-entity-to-multiple-tables